# How do I make the still image of the animation leave the screen?

Tags: html, css, animation

Sorry if the wording of the question was odd! Right now I coded an animation in which a train only runs every 20 minutes. I'm using `animation-delay` for 1200s. But the problem is that when the screen is waiting for the 20 minutes, it shows a still image of the train, but I want the train to not be in the screen until the animation time is starting as it should be when someone is waiting for a train at a platform. How can I achieve this? Any tips are appreciated!

---------CSS---------

```css
@keyframes gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
}

.platform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;

}

#wholetrain {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#trainwrapper {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
}

.train {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffcc00,#7575a3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: chug;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1200s;
}
```

------- HTML ------

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

 <div class="background"></div>

<div id="trainwrapper">
<div id="wholetrain">
  <div class="train"></div>
  <div class="train2"></div>
  <div class="train3"></div>
  <div class="train4"></div>
  <div class="train5"></div>
  <div class="train6"></div>
  <div class="train7"></div>
  <div class="train8"></div>
  <div class="train9"></div>
  <div class="train10"></div>
  <div class="platform"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, if you send your html code, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: I posted on the bottom!

Comment: The `chug` animation is not defined in your code. Is it supposed to be the `gradient` animation defined above? That one doesn't seem to do anything with the current `.train` properties unless there was maybe a background image? Please edit your code and [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).